# How can I read smart contract mapping in my frontend with ethers js?

Tags: javascript, solidity, smartcontracts, ethers.js

I wrote this command to return uint corresponding to the address in solidity.

```
mapping(address => uint256) public votesOf;
```

Now I want to read this in my frontend. I have used following code but it isn't working.

```
async function get_voting_results() {
const vote_result = await contract.isVoted["0xF2F823bAA7CABe76b35ad97a5039c20D36edd9a2"]
console.log(vote_result)
}
```

I've also tried using tuples but didn't make any change. Note I am using ethers js. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The name of the mapping should come after `await contract.`

It is an ethers function so use () instead of []
So your function should look like

```
async function get_voting_results() {
    const vote_result = await contract.votesOf("0xF2F823bAA7CABe76b35ad97a5039c20D36edd9a2")
    console.log(vote_result)
  }
```